# Not divisible by - LaTeX symbol

Tags: math-mode

I'm looking for a method to write divisibility (or, more precisely it's negation) for 2 numbers, a and b. The fragment of code:

```
$a \not\vdots b$
```

has two major problems:

1. The "cut" is not passing through the middle of the symbol;
2. Extremely low space between the symbol and b.

The second one is solvable by writing:

```
$a \not\vdots \ b$
```

So, how to solve the first one? And is there any other, more elegant solution, to the second one. I'm using article class, with few packages imported (I always use "ams-" family and ocasionally others).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest with this MWE to load  `centernot` package. It is possible to compare the differences with your fragment of `LaTeX` code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{centernot}


\begin{document}
$a \centernot\vdots b, \quad a \not\vdots b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The mathematical notation `a \nmid b` is not equivalent to `a \not\vdots \ b`. In fact, it's equivalent to `b \not\vdots \ a`

Comment: @MathStackExchange I have changhed the answer. Sorry for my misunderstanding.

Comment: That's a great one! Thanks a lot! (+1)

Comment: +1 for `centernot`: There are so many cool packages :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner :-) :-)....no no it is not very cool with the "Medicane" in these days in Mediterranean sea :-)

Answer (score 7):

Not to hijack Sebastiano's fine answer, I'd warn you against using `\vdots` that way, for a few reasons:

1. `\vdots` is not declared as a math relation;
2. `\vdots` is too high;
3. the bounding box of `\vdots` is “interesting”.

Here's a comparison of the bounding boxes of the symbol `\Div` I define below and `\vdots`:

[image]

Here's my proposal (but I'd use the vertical bar):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,centernot,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Div}{\mathrel{\Div@}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\nDiv}{\mathrel{\nDiv@}}

\newcommand{\Div@}{%
  \mkern2mu\nonscript\mkern-2mu % some space in subscripts
  \mathpalette\Div@@\relax
  \mkern2mu\nonscript\mkern-2mu
}
\newcommand{\Div@@}[2]{%
  \hbox{%
    \sbox\z@{$#1T$}%
    \vbox to \ht\z@{%
      \offinterlineskip\m@th
      \hbox{$#1.$}\vfil
      \hbox{$#1.$}\vfil
      \hbox{$#1.$}%
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\nDiv@}{\centernot\Div@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a\Div b\quad\scriptstyle a\Div b$

$a\mid b\quad\scriptstyle a\mid b$

$a\nDiv b\quad\scriptstyle a\nDiv b$

$a\nmid b\quad\scriptstyle a\nmid b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thank you and all users for your exquisite kindness. Thank you very much Prof. Very nice the use of the word hijack: "dirottare" ahahaha. :-)